# (batch) How to apply the output redirection to the last program of a line?

Tags: windows, batch-file, output-redirect

I have a line, in a batch script, from which I would like to capture the output. I would like to redirect it to a file. My problem is that there are 3 programs in that line, each calling the next. Here is the line:

```
start cmd /C java -jar Prog.jar -remote %1.xml > ProgOut.txt
```

At the moment, my guess is that the '>' is applied to start, while I would like to get the output of java (I actually get an empty file which is impossible if it is the java output)... I have tried having "" around the java part, but it obviously didn't work. I suppose that having the java command in another batch file would fix my problem, but I'd rather not duplicate script files, if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your batch file would look like this:

```
start cmd /C java -jar Prog.jar -remote %1.xml ^> ProgOut.txt
```

Found this on: http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/tips/jsi-tip-7733-how-do-i-redirect-the-output-of-a-program-that-i-launched-with-the-start-command-.aspx

Comment: I can't put java alone on its line and still have it 'start'ed in a new process/thread, right?

Comment: No, thank you! I just learned how to fork processes in windows :)